# CUDA installed on Mathematica 12.1, is running but CUDA-Functions still run on CPU

Tags: cudalink

I installed Mathematica and CUDA but all examples and functions are executed on CPU rather than GPU. I can check the time for a CUDAFourier vs Fourier and also don't see a GPU load in the taskmanager when using any CUDA-Function.

I checked on the random function below; I should get at least some differences. But I don't. Anyone any clue what I do wrong?

[image]

See CPU load vs GPU load.

[image]

CUDA:
[image]

Comment: There’s nothing here for us to go in, I’m afraid. However there have been a few CUDA troubleshooting questions on the site lately. Have you seen them? Ultimately You might have better luck with Wolfram Support.

Comment: Maybe the work load is not sufficient to see it in the windows process monitor. Create a function that runs longer on the GPU. Ideally some seconds. Then you might see the GPU load in the monitor. There are no evaluation times given in your post (AbsoluteTiming). You can also check on the compatibility of your GPU (CUDAInformation) with given lists in the internet. A CPU load may be attributed to the memory management (shift data back and forth between CPU and GPU).